# Function is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get working a small script like google add more files but i get an error like:

```
ReferenceError: addFile is not defined
```

The script im using is:

Javascript

```
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;
    p.appendChild(newElement);
}

function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}


var fileId = 0; // used by the addFile() function to keep track of IDs
function addFile() {
    fileId++; // increment fileId to get a unique ID for the new element
    var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" />' +
               '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement('file-' + fileId + ''); return false;">Remove</a>';
    addElement('files', 'p', 'file-' + fileId, html);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p>Upload file(s)</p>
    <div id="files">
        <p><input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" /></p>
    </div>
    <p><input type="button" value="Add File" onclick="addFile();" /></p>
</form>
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/neocastelli/qy7xfheb/

Is there a way to know why addFile is not defined?

Comment: You have a syntax error, which isn't very surprising considering you build HTML with event handlers by concatenating strings in Javascript, this happens so easily when you don't follow best practices. Note that the console of your browser points precisely to that error.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in escaping the strings.

```
var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
           '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement('file-' + fileId + ''); return false;">Remove</a>';
```

Has to be:

```
var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
           '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement("file-' + fileId + '"); return false;">Remove</a>';
```

Also the function is not global. You have to do:

```
window.addFile = function() {
```

[See the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o093kvo9/)

Comment: This is not enough. You also have to put this javascript in head tag not after DOM is ready or onload.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for the hint!, i see now that on remove it doesn;t remove the selected elementId, and it return an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }